# Troubleshooting a shutter that doesn't actuate

Tags: troubleshooting, mirrorless

I bought a used Fujifilm X-E1 camera body on ebay (details of setup below), and am trying to use it with an adapter and a set of K-mount lenses that I already owned. The lenses all worked fine with my old film SLR. After buying a memory card and putting in batteries, I seem to have a fully functional camera, except that ... er, it doesn't take pictures. I can see through the lens, I get a preview and indicators on the LCD, and it works when I set the aperture and focus. But when I depress the shutter button, nothing happens. I don't hear a click from the shutter, and there is no indication on the user interface that a picture has been taken.

My question is how to go about troubleshooting the problem. It's been 15 years since I've used my old film SLR, and I've never used a digital manual-focus camera, so it's quite possible that I'm just making some silly newbie mistake.

Page 3 of the manual describes an "indicator lamp" that tells you when the camera is ready to shoot. This never comes on for me, but as far as I can tell from the documentation, this is normal in manual focus mode -- it should only come on when you're using the camera in autofocus mode.

*Setup:*

- camera body: Fujifilm x-e1 ([PDF manual](https://www.fujifilmusa.com/shared/bin/xe1_manual_01.pdf))
- adapter: [Fotodiox Pentax K-Mount Lens Adapter](https://fotodioxpro.com/products/pk-fxrf)
- lens: 50 mm 1:1.7

*Steps I'm going through:*

1. Take off lens cap.
2. Turn on camera.
3. Set manual mode.
4. Set exposure to 1/500 s.
5. Push shutter button, feel a first and second click.
6. There is no sound from the shutter. Nothing appears to happen in the LCD user interface, and there is no indication that an exposure has been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this camera, but is it possible that you need to enable some kind of "release shutter with no lens attached" setting? What I'm thinking is, since there is no electronic communication between the camera and adapter (I assume), maybe your camera believes there is no lens attached.

Yes, I just checked the manual. See page 72, setting "Shoot without lens".